# How to get a Date from a mat-date-picker and a mat select with time?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm using Angular calendar to show some events. So every event has these parameters:

```
event:{
    title: string,
    start: Date,
    end: Date
};
```

Since material doesn't have a date-time picker, I'm using separately datepicker to select a date and then mat select for the time(8AM-18AM range).
I have something like this:

```
  <div class = "date-picker">

    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Seleziona giorno</mat-label>
      <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="date" name = "date">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <div class ="time-picker">
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Orario</mat-label>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="time" name = "time">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let time of times" [value]="time">{{time}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to "create" a Date comprehensive of time from the two, how can I do that?

The date format is like this:

new Date(2021, 6, 1, 12, 30, 0, 0)

In my .ts file I simple do:

```
this.event = {
      start: new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getUTCMonth(), this.date.getUTCDay(), this.time, 0, 0, 0),
```

etc...}

I need start to be a proper Date format from "date" and "time"
Thanks

Comment: Include your component.ts file. It is there where the fields/properties `date` and `time` live and they are the things from which you probably need to build the date.

Comment: I put an edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

`getDay` is the day of week. You want `getDate`. And don't use the UTC versions if you want your local timezone used (which you do because that's what the calendar will use).

Try this expression:

`new Date(this.date.getFullYear(), this.date.getMonth(), this.date.getDate(), this.time)`

This also assumes that your `times` are a set of values from 0 to 23.